# vb.net accdb memo to RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Been trying to figure out how to Read the content of a memo enriched Text field in an .accdb Microsoft Access Database for hours now. Found Nothing until now.

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Using Connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Drizzt\Desktop\App\iFoody\iFoody\iFoodyDB.accdb")

        Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE ID=1"

        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, Connection)
            Connection.Open()

            Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
            Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            Reader.Read()
            Directions_Field.Text = Reader(5)
            Reader.Close()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

When doing that, I get the content of the field in HTML format and can't figure out how to properly convert / transfert the data with the formating included.

regards,

Comment: In-built RichTextBox does not support rendering HTML tagged content directly. You can take leads from [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12172/An-extended-RichTextBox-to-save-and-load-quot-HTML) or [Expert-Exchange post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_23877596.html)

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use ".savefile" and ".loadfile" and save the .rtf somewhere instead to make it less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Windows Forms project you're talking about then the standard RichTextBox control is not going to be of much help. (At least, not without a substantial amount of extra work.)

I have used the HtmlEditorControl available at Carl Nolan's MSDN blog here:

[WinForms HTML Editor](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WinForms-HTML-Editor-01dbce1a)

and it has worked very well for me.